# How to filter GraphQL query?

Tags: graphql

I'm new to GraphQL and got stuck in a query. Well, this is sample GQL that returns every record in database:

```
        {
            viewer {
                savingsAccount {
                    id
                    feed {
                        id
                        __typename
                        title
                        detail
                        postDate
                        ... on TransferInEvent {
                            amount
                            originAccount {
                                name
                            }
                        }
                        ... on TransferOutEvent {
                            amount
                            destinationAccount {
                                name
                            }
                        }
                        ... on TransferOutReversalEvent {
                            amount
                        }
                        ... on BillPaymentEvent {
                            amount
                        }
                        ... on DebitPurchaseEvent {
                            amount
                        }
                        ... on BarcodePaymentEvent {
                            amount
                        }
                        ... on DebitWithdrawalFeeEvent {
                            amount
                        }
                        ... on DebitWithdrawalEvent {
                            amount
                        }    
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is sample return:

```
    {
        "data": {
            "viewer": {
                "savingsAccount": {
                    "id": "5c8fe258-34fd-4bdc-bfb6-761bc78435df",
                    "feed": [{
                            "id": "5fcd6040-cf19-4dbf-be25-47d2f1a7a29b",
                            "__typename": "DebitPurchaseEvent",
                            "title": "Test",
                            "detail": "Test $$",
                            "postDate": "2020-12-06",
                            "amount": 59.7
                        }, {
                            "id": "5fcd5bbd-fc70-4d87-944d-d0a186559289",
                            "__typename": "DebitPurchaseEvent",
                            "title": "Test",
                            "detail": "Test $$",
                            "postDate": "2020-12-06",
                            "amount": 30.0
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

How do I apply filter to return some specific postDate? I mean, after, before, etc. This attribute is stored as string but I believe it is possible to do some convertion.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: just extend your resolver to accept and use filtering arguments

Comment: Look at this documentation: https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/core/queries/query-filters.html

Comment: @gospecomid12 this is a specific implementation, valid only for hasura graphql engine ... however can be used as inspiration

Comment: @xadm I'm trying to call API through Insomnia. If I send query as is, it returns all records bu can't find a way to filter based on date range and I have no access to backend. Any other suggestions? Thanks!